# How to have two models reference each other Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model

I have the following code:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    summery = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    key = models.IntegerField()
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    complete = models.BooleanField()
    invite_sent = models.DateTimeField()
    on = models.ForeignKey(Member, blank = True) #<----


class Member(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game) #<----
```

The "on" foreign key links to one of the members (whose turn it is). All members of a game have their "game" foreign key set to the game they are on. The problem is that Django won't let me reference a class before it has been declared, and since I can't declare them simultaneously...

Edit: To clear things up, here's an example. If there were five members playing one game, all five would have foreign keys to the game. The game on the other hand would have one foreign key to the particular member whose turn it was.

Comment: Might not be appropriate here, but in general, you can create a ForeignKey to a class you haven't declared yet by passing the name of the class as a string instead of the class itself.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The [Django documentation for the ForeignKey field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) states:

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

So in your case, that would be:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    # Other fields...
    on = models.ForeignKey('Member', blank = True)

class Member(models.Model):
    # Other fields...
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
```

Comment: To me, constantly using the `'app.model'` notation for `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField` and `ManyToManyField` is very good practice. I've used this to split models files into one file per model, which is far more readable.

Comment: @SteveK This helped me solve a circular import problem, thanks!

Comment: How would you go about saving this relationship given the `null=False` default arguments?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just wonder, is this a good or normal practice or is it a hack?

Comment: What if That model should not be able to stay blank?

Comment: If your model lives in a different app, use `myapp.Member`, details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626648/fields-e300-field-defines-a-relation-with-model-which-is-either-not-installed

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to have the two models reference each other with foreign keys. Remove the line:

```
on = models.ForeignKey(Member, blank = True) #<----
```

and logically your `Member`'s will still be associated to different `Game`'s (and this makes more sense because a member can belong to one game at a time, whereas a game can have more than one member).

You can use [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) to figure out which members are on a particular game.

Comment: I probable didn't make my situation clear (or maybe I'm not understanding your answer). If you had for instants 5 members all playing one game, they would all reference the same game. But the "on" foreign key would only reference the persons who's turn it was (a single member).