# Django 1.7 upgrade - Field defines a relation with model which is either not installed, or is abstract

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I am attempting to update from Django 1.6 to 1.7. Since updating, I have started receiving a large amount of errors for seemingly all ForeignKey or M2M fields that use the string style reference such as 'app.Model' as documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

The errors look like:

> app.NotificationSettings.st_user: (fields.E300) Field defines a
>   relation with model 'account.STUser', which is either not installed,
>   or is abstract.

The model itself with ForeignKey looks like the following:

```
class NotificationSettings(models.Model):
    st_user = models.ForeignKey('account.STUser')
```

The account app is included in my INSTALLED_APPS within my settings file so I am not sure why it would consider this model is not installed. I have experimented with swapping the string style reference to referencing the actual model class after importing which seems to prevent the error for that field, but then I have run into a series of circular dependency issues.

I found a similar question here, but the given solution is already how my fields causing errors are defined so it doesn't help:

[(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model which is either not installed, or is abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626648/fields-e300-field-defines-a-relation-with-model-which-is-either-not-installed)

These errors seem to be related to the [App-loading refactor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor) documented in the Django 1.7 release notes, but I have not found any specific documentation on changes that might need to be made to ForeignKey or M2M field notation.

Is there something I am overlooking that could resolve these errors?
Thanks in advance.