# "(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model which is either not installed, or is abstract."

Tags: python

These are the models of my app but there is an error as the title above.

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey('question', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

import datetime


from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Is it possible to fix this problem?

> ERRORS: votes.Choice.question: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation
>   with model 'Question', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Comment: Why do You have 2 definitions of `Question` class?

Comment: Is it the cause?

Comment: Don't know `Django` very well, but I doubt it will work as intended. If I'm not wrong, second definition will override first one.

Comment: u r right lol , I just fooled myself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model which is either not installed, or is abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626648/fields-e300-field-defines-a-relation-with-model-which-is-either-not-installed)