# Am getting an error while using the django framework

Tags: django, django-models

So basically, I am trying to create a Local Library as part of a course I am doing based around Django. My resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_Views. I am currently on the part where I have to create my own Author. Here is my models.py code for Authors:

```
class Author(models.Model):  
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)    
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)  

    def get_absolute_url(self):  
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])  

    def __str__(self):  
        return f'{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}
```

The message I am recieving in my command prompt is this:

```
catalog.Book.author: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Author', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

If you require any additional information, please just tell me. Thank you.

EDIT: my file path to models.py is...

C:\Users\truyo\django_project\locallibrary\catalog\models.py

and settings.py is

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'catalog',
]
```

Comment: where is `Author` model& what file path? also show your settings.py part with installed apps list

Comment: ok i will do , i will edit the post

Comment: try to add `'locallibrary'` to registered apps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model which is either not installed, or is abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626648/fields-e300-field-defines-a-relation-with-model-which-is-either-not-installed)

Comment: @Stevy, it kind of does but since i am a beginner at this whole django thing, i don't know how to implement it into mine, since i saw it last night but did not quite understand it

Comment: Can you post both the `Author` and the `Book` models?

Comment: Oh don't worry, it has been resolved, the issue was in my html files